# SaveChanges doesn't do anything using LINQ Entities over OData

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, odata

In some cases I have been able to trick it into detecting a change using UpdateObject:

```
public UpdateOrderDescription(int userId)
{
    var entities = new DatabaseEntities(new Uri("http://SomeServer/OrderService.svc")) { UsePostTunneling = true};

    var order = (from o in entities.Orders where o.UserId == userId select o).Single();

    order.Description = "Hello";
    entities.UpdateObject(order);
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

But that doesn't work when using many-to-many relationship using navigation properties, since I can not perform UpdateObject on a navigation property.

Comment: Help me to get this. Do you mean that your code snippet works, but there is another scenario that doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I hoped that it should detect the changes automatically (as it states in almost all documentation and discussions I have seen).

Secondly I don't know how to tell the entity framework that the navigation collection has changed.

I guess that the correct answer that it simply doesn't work that way? You need to describe all the changes you are doing to the entities. Which in practice renders the whole thing more or less useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756361.aspx

In short the client library for WCF DS needs to be notified about changes you want to make. By default that is done using the UpdateObject, SetLink, AddLink and similar methods on the context.